# MYSQL to sum income by dates and payment type

Tags: mysql

I want to get the income sum of each day between a period BUT separated by payment type.

[image]

My query so far is:

```
SELECT event_date, sum(amount) FROM moneyflow WHERE `event_date` BETWEEN "2022-10-01" AND "2022-10-03" 
GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY `event_date`
```

The results from it are:

[image]

but I would like them to be separated by payment type, How should I change the query to achieve the results in the way I want them?
for example
[image]
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're looking for a pivot table, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be by using `case` statements:

```
SELECT event_date,
    sum(case when payment_type = "cash" then amount else 0 end) as cash,
    sum(case when payment_type = "card" then amount else 0 end) as card,
    sum(amount) total
FROM moneyflow
WHERE `event_date` BETWEEN "2022-10-01" AND "2022-10-03" 
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY `event_date`
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e471f5/2)

Comment: diiN :) TRUE :))), maybe is time to rest , Thanks, I will accept it in minute

Comment: Well but after I tested I discovered it prints 3 rows per date instade of 1 row with 2 amounts.. Isn't it possible to achieve the results per date in 1 row?

Comment: Exactly, I just was going to answer with the same query when I saw your answer! Accepted, Thank you !